# libQt5MultimediaQuick.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, qml, pyqt5, qt5, qtmultimedia

I was working on a project called RaspMedia(my project folder's name is also that). I combined QML and python together using PyQt5.

I've tried to import QtMultimedia using the import statement `import QtMutimedia 5.14` in my main.qml file.

This is my complete python code.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl,QMimeDatabase,QVariant,QFileInfo,QMetaObject,Q_ARG
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
import os
import sys
home = os.environ["HOME"]+"/"
print(home)
currentPath = home

def getList(directory:type=str):
    a = os.popen("ls '"+directory+"'")
    b = []
    for i in a:
        b.append(i.replace("\n", ""))
    return b

def appendToList(mainList:type=list):
    for i in mainList:
        path = currentPath + i
        mime = QMimeDatabase().mimeTypeForFile(QFileInfo(path)).name()
        if mime == "inode/directory":
            anObject = {"type":"folder", "name":i, "path":path }
            QMetaObject.invokeMethod(win, "append", Q_ARG(QVariant, anObject))
            print(anObject)

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)
    myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", engine)


    engine.load(url)

    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
    appendToList(getList(home))

    win.show()

    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

Running it gave me error following

```
file:///home/newtron/RaspMedia/main.qml:5:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtMultimedia": Cannot load library /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/libdeclarative_multimedia.so: (libQt5MultimediaQuick.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

On the same side pyside smoothly ran script without any errors.

This is the complete output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/libdeclarative_multimedia.so`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff65783000)
    libQt5MultimediaQuick.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libQt5Multimedia.so.5 (0x00007fe0d8bdc000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007fe0d84b1000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fe0d7b9e000)
    libQt5QmlModels.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libQt5QmlModels.so.5 (0x00007fe0d7904000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007fe0d72b7000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fe0d6f0c000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fe0d6732000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fe0d64a6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe0d6287000)
    libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 (0x00007fe0d6082000)
    libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007fe0d5e32000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe0d5b1b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe0d5792000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe0d53f4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe0d51dc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe0d4deb000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe0d4bce000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe0d49c6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe0d47c2000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fe0d4577000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007fe0d40de000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007fe0d3d26000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007fe0d2343000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe0d2141000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe0d9143000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fe0d1f10000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fe0d1c5a000)
    libpulsecommon-11.1.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-11.1.so (0x00007fe0d19dc000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fe0d178f000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fe0d151d000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fe0d1247000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fe0d1015000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fe0d0e11000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fe0d0c06000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fe0d08ce000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fe0d06a6000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fe0d0422000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007fe0d0218000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007fe0cff9f000)
    libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007fe0cfd99000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fe0cfb95000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fe0cf97a000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fe0cf776000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fe0cf570000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fe0cf34a000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fe0cf12e000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fe0cee12000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fe0cebf8000)
    libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007fe0ce981000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007fe0ce778000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007fe0ce54d000)
    libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007fe0ce2a4000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fe0ce08f000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fe0cde7a000)
```

Do I need to install any

**Software Info**

- PyQt version: 5.14.1
- Qt version:5.14.1
- Python version:3.6
- os: Ubuntu
    18.04

Comment: what is the output of  `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/libdeclarative_multimedia.so:`?

Comment: i included it in question

Comment: what is the output of `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/../../lib/`? How did you install pyqt5?

Comment: I tried it to install using pip3 install PyQt5 but it doesn't work. `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0wf7j8ul/PyQt5/`. So I simply extracted the whl package to python dist-utils.

Comment: mmm, use `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and `sudo python3 -m pip install pyqt5`

Comment: it returns same error.`` file:///home/newtron/RaspMedia/main.qml:5:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtMultimedia": Cannot load library /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtMultimedia/libdeclarative_multimedia.so: (libQt5MultimediaQuick.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)``

Comment: QtMultimedia doesn't have any subdirectories. There are these files in QtMultimedia `libdeclarative_multimedia.so  plugins.qmltypes qmldir Video.qml`

Comment: Are you using conda?

Comment: No. I even don't know how to program with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how we can fix it. PyQt5 has an error with the MultiMediaQuick package. So I copied and pasted

- Qt5.14.1/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5MultimediaQuick.la
- Qt5.14.1/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5MultimediaQuick.so
- Qt5.14.1/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5MultimediaQuick.prl
- Qt5.14.1/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Multimedia.so.5.14.1
- Qt5.14.1/5.14.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5MultimediaQuick.so.5
  files to `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/` and some additional files such as gstreamer and include folders to it. Now it works perfect.